# FindOne followed by updateOne, using a single query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

By using the *"findOne"* method of mongoDb driver (**no mongoose**), can I use the retrieved document to update it later?

For example:

```
document.collection('myCollection').findOne({ _id: myId }, (err, foundDoc) => {
  // **I need to do some multiple checks in between**, so I don't want to use "findOneAndUpdate()"
  // foundDoc is the retrieved document. Can I use it directly for update? (something like "foundDoc.update()")
  document.collection('myCollection').updateOne({ _id: myId }, { $set: { name: 'John' } });
});
```

As you can see I am basically doing a second query by using the "updateOne" method (first it searches for the document and then it updates it). Can I avoid that somehow, and use the foundDoc directly for update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the same document, you don't have to call `.findOne()` followed by `.updateOne()` method. By default, `upsert` option is set to false in  `.upadateOne()`, so it will refuse to insert the document if not found else it will update.

```
 document.collection('myCollection').updateOne({ _id: myId }, { $set: { name: 'John' } });
```

`.updateOne` should be sufficient in your case.

Also if you want to add some filter conditions, `.updateOne()` supports that as below :

```
db.collection.updateOne(
   <filter>,   // you can place filters here
   <update>,
   {
     upsert: <boolean>,
     writeConcern: <document>,
     collation: <document>,
     arrayFilters: [ <filterdocument1>, ... ]
   }
)
```

Link : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/

Comment: I used findOne because I wanted to do some checks on the document (each check could trigger a different http response) and only after those checks I wanted to update the document.

Comment: In that case, if possible you can use filters with `updateOne()` method. Added more details in answer.